# IOS SwiftUI accessibility Focus goes on Status bar. How to make focus stay on single view

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, accessibility

I have scenario where i need to keep focus of accessibility on single view until user perform any another swipe action. but in my case focus is automatically moving to status bar items like battery and network status. don't know how to stop it from moving to status bar automatically.